# Regenerate SSAS multidimentional partitions files from the database

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, multidimensional-cube, ssdt-2019

I have an ssas cube and I want to create the solution with ssdt on visual studio.
I need to generate the .partations file of the cube.

When I do New Project -> Import from server (multidimentional and data mining)
The project is created but the .partations file are empty (2ko)

I tried with VS2019, 2017 and BIDS2008R2, it's always the same problem

Any idea about this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue when we import from a SSAS database containing custom partitions.

To get the correct partitions, you need to just open the cube (in the Visual Studio Solution) and navigate to the partitions tab.

The moment you select the partitions tab, you can notice, the "star" symbol in the tab denoting that the project has been updated.

You will notice that the partitions file is now updated with the latest partitions.

[image]